# including script doesn't work in web.py

Tags: javascript, python, web.py

everyone.I wanna include javascript in the html(webpy templates),but it doesn't work.the javascript code in the html works very well...

following is the main python file(main.py):

```
urls = ('/main','main')
render = web.template.render('templates/')

class main:
  def GET(self):
    return render.main()

app = web.application(urls,globals())

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run()
```

templates/main.htm:

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="include.js"></script>
<script>
  alert(location.href);  //this line works..
</script>
</body>
```

include.js:

```
alert('test');  //this line doesn't work
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must put the `include.js` file in a "static/js" directory at the root of your project and `src` should be "static/js/include.js".