# including external script doen't work in web.py (html template)

Tags: javascript, html, web.py

I include script in html (web template), it doen't work when I visited it by http://127.0.0.1:8080/main, but in local when I double click the html file, the script can work.

I find one question here, but the answer doen't work either:
[including script doesn't work in web.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289446/including-script-doesnt-work-in-web-py)

```
# web.py
import web

urls = ('/main', 'main')
render = web.template.render('templates/')


class main:
    def GET(self):
        return render.main()


app = web.application(urls, globals())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Below is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>title</title>
    <script src="echarts.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello world!+++</p>
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" means ... cannot find the js file, or file is loaded but not executed, or nothing is returned by /main...?

Answer (score 1):

How is your directory structure defined? Do you have `js` files in *static* folder ?

For any static scripts such as `css` and `js` to work, `web.py` expects them in a static folder under main app folder.
Here is general structure I normally go with.

```
/app.py           #main app 

/static           #static data
       /css       #css
       /js        #javascript
       /images    #images

/templates        #html templates
```

These folders can be accessed using relative path in `html` file.
For e.g. Once you have defined above directory structure, in your `html` file simply put in,

```
<script src="static/js/yourJavaScript.js" ></script>
```

When you launch `app.py`, the app then would look into static/js folder for your javascript and it should work.
I've my setup working as above.